# VC++ says "no overloaded function takes 7 arguments" I say YES IT DOES!

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

In my `PDBComponent` class's header file, I just created a new constructor for a grand total of two constructors:

```
class PDBComponent {
    public:
        PDBComponent(string name,double min_current,double nom_current,
                     double max_current, EPSCommands* command_ptr, double delay);
        PDBComponent(string name,double min_current,double nom_current,
                     double max_current, EPSCommands* command_ptr, EPSFault* fault_ptr ,double delay);
...
```

And when I use the first constructor, I get no compile error.  Like so:

```
PDBComponent component = PDBComponent("STX"     ,0.1,  0.5,  1.0
        ,new EPSCommands( 1.0, 3.0),0.0);
```

However when I use the second constructor I get a compile error::

```
PDBComponent component = PDBComponent("STX"     ,0.1,  0.5,  1.0
        ,new EPSCommands( 1.0, 3.0), new EPSFault(EPSFault::OpenCircuit,2.0),0.0);
```

The compile error:

> error C2661: 'fs5system::PDBComponent::PDBComponent' : no overloaded function takes 7 arguments

I thought that maybe I was working with one header file while the compiler was looking at another, so I commented out the first constructor.  The compiler showed that it was recompiling the PDBComponent.cpp and then showed an error:

> error C2511: 'fs5system::PDBComponent::PDBComponent(std::string,double,double,double,fs5system::EPSCommands *,double)' : overloaded member function not found in 'fs5system::PDBComponent'

...which indicates that the compiler is indeed looking at the correct header file.

Anybody know why I'm seeing this behavior?

I'm compiling with Visual Studios C++.

---

More Clues:

I just added the following line to the class definition in the header file:

```
bool trash() {return true;}
```

And tested it with

```
PDBComponent* component;
component = new PDBComponent("STX"     ,0.1,  0.5,  1.0
        ,new EPSCommands( 1.0, 3.0),0.0);

cout << component->trash() << endl;
```

in my main file.  When compiling, the PDBComponent header is again compiled.  I get error message:

> error C2039: 'trash' : is not a member of 'fs5system::PDBComponent'

Comment: When you comment out the first ctor, do you still get the error on the second usage?

Comment: Is that exactly how you call it? (What's with the spaces after "STX" and why does the error message call "STX" a `std::string` when it's not?)

Comment: @GMan: the "STX" string would be implicitly converted to a std::string.

Comment: @Michael: Right, but not when the compiler is looking for a specific function. It should say "I can't find a function with these parameters..." and then list `(const char*, ...)` in the arguments it was trying to match.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem with some fake code (empty class, empty body of constructor taking 7 parameters similar parameters to yours)?

Comment: @Tomek - I'm at that point I guess... :-( ... stay tuned

Comment: @GMan: I think the `C2511` comes when the compiler sees the definition of the 6-parameter constructor, but there's no prototype for it in the class (since it was commented out for the test) - not from trying to call the 6-parameter prototype.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the above or re-type it into the question?

Comment: @all - see "new clues" section of question

Comment: @Martin - I copied and pasted the code

Comment: I would go for some intermediate file corruption. Do a full rebuild.

Comment: The comma is misplaced before the 7th argument.  Hmm, coincidence.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It is not misplaced, it is overloaded ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you get an error when the 6-parameter constructor is being compiled when you've commented it out in the header - but is that the same source file that contains the *calls* to the constructor?  Is it possible that a different header is being used for that compilation somehow (maybe precompiled header weirdness is involved).

Try using the `/showIncludes` option ("C++ | Advanced | Show includes" in the IDE's project settings) and/or turning off precompiled headers and see if you get any further clues or better behavior.

Comment: I'm trying /showIncludes... there's a lot of includes it seems... and I think you might be the winner... stay tuned!

Comment: So what exactly was the problem?

Comment: grepping through the /showIncludes output for the particular header's name will probably net you good results really quickly...

Comment: And we have a winner!  Thank you so much.  I did a lot of refactoring with my project this morning and in the process I had duplicate files wondering around.  Although I thought the files in my solution explorer were all pointing to the new directory, some were still pointing at the old directory, and so I was editing a different file than I thought I was.  /showIncludes pointed this out.  (Inserting /showIncludes in my c++ toolbox.)

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging powers think `EPSFault` is not defined where you're using it there, or that this class is being included in a precompiled header (in which case that header needs to be rebuilt).

Note that the code there is NOT exception safe because you've put two `new`s in a single statement -- if the first one succeeds, and the second throws `std::bad_alloc`, then the memory allocated by the first is leaked.

Comment: +1 For the "exception safe" comment.  I'm new to C++ and today I'm really feeling the GOTCHAS!

Comment: I'll give you another +1 if you can tell me where to get a psychic debugger.

Comment: @John: His name is Raymond Chen.